# Silly sprintf() question

Tags: php, printf

How do I add the SQL wildcard characters to this:

```
 sprintf("SELECT robot FROM robots WHERE robot LIKE '%s'",strtolower($user_agent));
```

as

```
 sprintf("SELECT robot FROM robots WHERE robot LIKE '%%s%'",strtolower($user_agent));
```

blows up in a spectacular ball of flame,

PS sorry for the rather basic question. I'm cutting down on my coffee these days.

Comment: Why use sprintf here (no formatting) instead of string concatenation or simple variable substitution?

Comment: Side note: you're opening yourself to code injection by using such constructs...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A literal `%` is specifed as `%%`, so you want `"... LIKE '%%%s%%'"`

Comment: Keep voting this up, I don't have a gold badge yet :p